# Why I don't get any error here in my interface implementation?

Tags: c#

** Take a look at Edits sections**

I have an interface

```
IInterface<TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO> where TYPE_TWO : string
{
    void foo();
}
```

then I have a `BaseClass`

```
class BaseClass<TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO> where TYPE_TWO: string
```

and now I would like to implement in `BaseClass`, `IInterfase`

```
class BaseClass<TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO> where TYPE_TWO: string, IInterface<TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO>{}
```

problem is - I expect that VisualStudio tell me that

> You have to implement IInterface methods foo()

But I don't get any such notification... And also I am able to compile the project... It is seems to me strange, because I have a class that implements theinterface, but not it's methods.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

My actual code

```
    interface ILooperable<in TASK_TYPE, in CALLBACK_TYPE> where CALLBACK_TYPE : ILooperableCallback<TASK_TYPE>  
    {
        void Start();
        void Put(TASK_TYPE task);
        void DeleteTask(TASK_TYPE task);
        void SetCallback(CALLBACK_TYPE callback);
        void Quit();
    }
```

```
    interface ILooperableCallback<in TASK_TYPE>
    {
        void Finish(TASK_TYPE task);
    }
```

```
    class BaseLooper<TASK_TYPE, CALLBACK_TYPE> where CALLBACK_TYPE : ILooperableCallback<TASK_TYPE>,
        ILooperable<TASK_TYPE, CALLBACK_TYPE>
    {
        //Here I am expect to get lack of interface implementation warning
    }
```

**EDIT**

I will ask in other words how can I tell the `BaseLooper` that I want that it's second paramert implements ILooperableCallback and also class themselves implements interface?

In this line `lass BaseLooper<TASK_TYPE, CALLBACK_TYPE> where CALLBACK_TYPE : ILooperableCallback<TASK_TYPE>` I tell that I want that it's second paramert implements ILooperableCallback, right?

and it this line `.... ,ILooperable<TASK_TYPE, CALLBACK_TYPE>` I tell class themselves implements interface ILooperable, right?

Comment: Can you please post the actual code you're using, rather than code that won't compile - otherwise, it's very hard to see what your issue is. (For example, you can't constrain a generic type to `string` and you are missing the `interface` keyword).

Comment: IInterface<TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO> where TYPE_TWO : string doesn't even compile

Comment: Please write a runnable example so we can help you

Comment: @MarcoSalerno and others: Guys, what exactly are you expecting, or missing in the question? The problem (expected vs. actual outcome) is clearly described, and all the code required to reproduce the problem is contained in there.

Comment: I voted to reopen since it seems fairly clear what this question is about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is like this:

```
interface IInterface<TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO>
{
    void foo();
}

class BaseClass<TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO> where TYPE_TWO : IInterface<TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO>
{
}
```

The declaration of the class just says that TYPE_TWO must implement `IInterface<TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO>` - it says nothing about the class itself implementing that interface, so it compiles just fine.

If you wanted the class itself to implement the interface, you'd write it like this:

```
class BaseClass<TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO>: IInterface<TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO>
{
}
```

And now it won't compile:

```
Error CS0535  'BaseClass<TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO>' does not implement interface member 'IInterface<TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO>.foo()'
```

Note that if you also wanted to keep the constraint on TYPE_TWO, you can include that as well:

```
class BaseClass<TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO>
    : IInterface<TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO> 
      where TYPE_TWO : IInterface<TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO>
{
}
```

This will yield the same compile error - but at this point, I suspect the declaration has become somewhat unwieldy and difficult to understand...

So to answer your question, the declaration of your class should look like this:

```
class BaseLooper<TASK_TYPE, CALLBACK_TYPE>
    : ILooperableCallback<TASK_TYPE>
    where CALLBACK_TYPE : ILooperableCallback<TASK_TYPE>, ILooperable<TASK_TYPE, CALLBACK_TYPE>
{
    // ...
}
```

The syntax is thus:

- The type(s) after the colon (`:`) defines what the class itself must implement.
- The type(s) after the `where` defines the constraints on the type parameters.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko This answer still applies to the edited question.

Comment: Maybe for the sake of clarity, add a type constraint for one fo the generic parameters to `BaseClass` in your corrected version - just to show how the `where` clause would actually go *after* any inherited/implemented classes/interfaces.

Comment: Edited the question one more time

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Edited the question one more time

Comment: Finally I got the answer thanks. Issue was in order... I thought that at the begginer I have to set types and then implementation of interface themselves, but actually it is vise versa

Answer (score 0):

In you code in `BaseLooper` class you are telling that whoever will use this class, the client should give an implementation of `CALLBAK_TYPE`where `CALLBACK_TYPE` is derived from `ILooperableCallback<TASK_TYPE>,ILooperable<TASK_TYPE, CALLBACK_TYPE>`. This definition of `BaseClass` doesn't tell that `BaseLooper` is a implementation of  `ILooperableCallback<TASK_TYPE>`.

```
interface ILooperable<in TASK_TYPE, in CALLBACK_TYPE> where CALLBACK_TYPE : ILooperableCallback<TASK_TYPE>
{
    void Start();
    void Put(TASK_TYPE task);
    void DeleteTask(TASK_TYPE task);
    void SetCallback(CALLBACK_TYPE callback);
    void Quit();
}
interface ILooperableCallback<in TASK_TYPE>
{
    void Finish(TASK_TYPE task);
}

class BaseLooper<TASK_TYPE, CALLBACK_TYPE> where CALLBACK_TYPE : ILooperableCallback<TASK_TYPE>,
    ILooperable<TASK_TYPE, CALLBACK_TYPE>
{
    //Here I am expect to get lack of interface implementation warning
}
```

Suppose you want to a derived class `ClientClass` implementing `BaseLooper` class then you will have to provide an implementation of `CALLBACK_TYPE`. And when you will try to implement `CALLBACK_TYPE`, your desired error will surely show up.